# Does PDO care if query with place holders uses an non-associated array?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

I had a query in my application that looked like this:

```
$stmt = db::db()->prepare('INSERT INTO t(a,b) VALUES :a,:b)');
$stmt->execute(array(1,2));
```

Later, I had an unrelated error, and when reviewing this script, I asked myself why it ever worked previously.  I would have expected I should have used

```
$stmt->execute(array('a'=>1,'b'=>2));
```

But, it seems to work?

Is it acceptable to use an non-associated array with a prepared statement where the placeholders are array keys and not question marks?

Not that I will get into this practice, but this had me stumped and I just need to know.

Thank you

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix  To my total surprise, it seems to work either way.

Comment: I think it only matters when doing bind, the name that is ( obviously its not an array in that case ).  Otherwise it assumes order, and falls back to the ? placeholder type, it might work but if they are in the wrong order you will have problems.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix.  I guess so.  It was just so unexpected that I thought my code must have been changed as it couldn't have previously worked.  Oh well...  At least know I know.

Comment: I never do it with the ?, andway and seldom write actual queries these days, mostly I use an ORM.

Comment: Hm. Is that code from PDO? So you need remove one array definition.

Comment: @user1032531 Did you get an error when you ran the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes PDO **does** care, In this scenario prepare would not fail because the client sends a partial query to the database server,
 this query has to be completely minus the data so it can be pre-processed. 
 The client then sends the data, either once or multiple times, the server then executes the pre-processed query with the data.

Howerver the following exception should have been raised when executing:

```
{ "HY093",  "Invalid parameter number" }
```

If you read the source code of PDO for the execute function you will see the following piece of code that throws this error:

```
if (HASH_KEY_IS_STRING == zend_hash_get_current_key_ex(Z_ARRVAL_P(input_params),
            &param.name, &str_length, &num_index, 0, NULL)) {
    /* yes this is correct.  we don't want to count the null byte.  ask wez */
    param.namelen = str_length - 1;
    param.paramno = -1;
} else {
    /* we're okay to be zero based here */
    if (num_index < 0) {
        pdo_raise_impl_error(stmt->dbh, stmt, "HY093", NULL TSRMLS_CC);
        RETURN_FALSE;
    }
    param.paramno = num_index;
}
```

I am not sure how it worked for you so I would make sure PDO errormode attribute is set.

You still have to be careful because you must take care of proper order of the elements in the array that we are passing to the `PDOStatement::execute()` method.

`execute()` full function from source code

```
/* {{{ proto bool PDOStatement::execute([array $bound_input_params])
   Execute a prepared statement, optionally binding parameters */
static PHP_METHOD(PDOStatement, execute)
{
    zval *input_params = NULL;
    int ret = 1;
    PHP_STMT_GET_OBJ;

    if (FAILURE == zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC, "|a!", &input_params)) {
        RETURN_FALSE;
    }

    PDO_STMT_CLEAR_ERR();

    if (input_params) {
        struct pdo_bound_param_data param;
        zval **tmp;
        uint str_length;
        ulong num_index;

        if (stmt->bound_params) {   
            zend_hash_destroy(stmt->bound_params);
            FREE_HASHTABLE(stmt->bound_params);
            stmt->bound_params = NULL;
        }

        zend_hash_internal_pointer_reset(Z_ARRVAL_P(input_params));
        while (SUCCESS == zend_hash_get_current_data(Z_ARRVAL_P(input_params), (void*)&tmp)) {
            memset(&param, 0, sizeof(param));

            if (HASH_KEY_IS_STRING == zend_hash_get_current_key_ex(Z_ARRVAL_P(input_params),
                        &param.name, &str_length, &num_index, 0, NULL)) {
                /* yes this is correct.  we don't want to count the null byte.  ask wez */
                param.namelen = str_length - 1;
                param.paramno = -1;
            } else {
                /* we're okay to be zero based here */
                if (num_index < 0) {
                    pdo_raise_impl_error(stmt->dbh, stmt, "HY093", NULL TSRMLS_CC);
                    RETURN_FALSE;
                }
                param.paramno = num_index;
            }

            param.param_type = PDO_PARAM_STR;
            MAKE_STD_ZVAL(param.parameter);
            MAKE_COPY_ZVAL(tmp, param.parameter);

            if (!really_register_bound_param(&param, stmt, 1 TSRMLS_CC)) {
                if (param.parameter) {
                    zval_ptr_dtor(&param.parameter);
                }
                RETURN_FALSE;
            }

            zend_hash_move_forward(Z_ARRVAL_P(input_params));
        }
    }

    if (PDO_PLACEHOLDER_NONE == stmt->supports_placeholders) {
        /* handle the emulated parameter binding,
         * stmt->active_query_string holds the query with binds expanded and 
         * quoted.
         */

        ret = pdo_parse_params(stmt, stmt->query_string, stmt->query_stringlen,
            &stmt->active_query_string, &stmt->active_query_stringlen TSRMLS_CC);

        if (ret == 0) {
            /* no changes were made */
            stmt->active_query_string = stmt->query_string;
            stmt->active_query_stringlen = stmt->query_stringlen;
            ret = 1;
        } else if (ret == -1) {
            /* something broke */
            PDO_HANDLE_STMT_ERR();
            RETURN_FALSE;
        }
    } else if (!dispatch_param_event(stmt, PDO_PARAM_EVT_EXEC_PRE TSRMLS_CC)) {
        PDO_HANDLE_STMT_ERR();
        RETURN_FALSE;
    }
    if (stmt->methods->executer(stmt TSRMLS_CC)) {
        if (stmt->active_query_string && stmt->active_query_string != stmt->query_string) {
            efree(stmt->active_query_string);
        }
        stmt->active_query_string = NULL;
        if (!stmt->executed) {
            /* this is the first execute */

            if (stmt->dbh->alloc_own_columns && !stmt->columns) {
                /* for "big boy" drivers, we need to allocate memory to fetch
                 * the results into, so lets do that now */
                ret = pdo_stmt_describe_columns(stmt TSRMLS_CC);
            }

            stmt->executed = 1;
        }

        if (ret && !dispatch_param_event(stmt, PDO_PARAM_EVT_EXEC_POST TSRMLS_CC)) {
            RETURN_FALSE;
        }

        RETURN_BOOL(ret);
    }
    if (stmt->active_query_string && stmt->active_query_string != stmt->query_string) {
        efree(stmt->active_query_string);
    }
    stmt->active_query_string = NULL;
    PDO_HANDLE_STMT_ERR();
    RETURN_FALSE;
}
/* }}} */
```